# Gradle pass dynamic value as system property to method

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-eclipse

I have a gradle project that has a calculated variable I need to pass into an application.  When i attempt to do this is passes a null value, not the set value I want.

I have the below example file that demonstrates the issue to run just do gradle foo
I want both lines of output to be 4.

```
def String sum

task add {
    doLast {
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
            def result = exec {
                executable = 'sh'
                args = ['-c', 'echo $((2 + 2))']
                standardOutput = os
            }
            sum = os.toString()
            afterEvaluate {
                tasks.foo {
                    systemProperty "foo.bar", "${sum}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task foo {
    doLast{
        println System.properties['foo.bar']
        println "${sum}"
    }
}

tasks.foo.dependsOn( add )
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this (note the simple assignment to `System.properties['foo.bar']`):

```
def String sum

task add {
    doLast {
        new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
            def result = exec {
                executable = 'sh'
                args = ['-c', 'echo $((2 + 2))']
                standardOutput = os
            }
            sum = os.toString()
            System.properties['foo.bar'] = sum
        }
    }
}

task foo {
    doLast{
        println System.properties['foo.bar']
        println "${sum}"
    }
}

tasks.foo.dependsOn( add )
```

then this is the output:

```
$ gradle foo 
:add
:foo
4

4
```